# What is the difference between upvoting and favoriting a question?

Tags: support, bookmarks

When should I favorite a question instead of just upvoting it?  Is there anything special about favoriting a question?  Also, is it the typical practice to always upvote a question you favorited?

Comment: Uh... other than it saves the question in your favorites list? Kind of like a bookmark?

Comment: Where is my favorites list then?  I've looked all over for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5429360/daniel-grosskopf?tab=favorites

Comment: *"I've looked all over for it"* - try going to your user control panel and typing "favorites" into your browser's search function. Such a wonderful time saving tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The favourite facility notes things that are important or interesting to you. Voting tells other people that the post is useful or not.

Favouriting does not imply a post is good, for instance people often favourite bad posts that they have voted to close to remind them to vote to delete once they are closed. I.e. you mark a post as a favourite if you might need or want to go back to it at some future time.

You can find what you've favourited in [the favorites tab of your profile](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites).

Comment: Robert, could you edit you're post to include the information about where to find everything you favorited?  That's where I was the most confused since I hadn't seen that feature yet.

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Comment: If that's the case, why does getting Favorited award points?

Comment: @Goose It doesn't award points.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah, my mistake, I thought I just was. Thanks.